# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug' ccid-1.1.5

Tags: java, android, gradle

i'm getting this error for several days, tried some solutions but it still gives me same error.

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\EDenetiS\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar] (Can't process class [com/scdroid/ccid/c.class] (Unknown verification type [29] in stack map frame))
>       at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)

**This library is that i want to use: compile files('libs/ccid-1.1.5.jar')**

**My gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "tr.gov.gib.edenetis"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
compile files('libs/akiscif-2.4.7.jar')
//    compile files('libs/android-support-annotations.jar')
compile files('libs/asn1rt-6.5.3.jar')
compile files('libs/ccid-1.1.5.jar')
compile files('libs/devsmartlib.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jcifs-1.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.16.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-asn-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-cmssignature-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-common-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-crypto-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-crypto-gnuprovider-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-infra-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-signature-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-smartcard-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-smartcard-android-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ma3api-smartcard-android-ccid-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar')
compile files('libs/sunpkcs11.jar')
compile files('libs/volley-1.0.0.jar')
}
```

Any solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

add dependecncies in your app level gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  compile'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: They are added as you can see.